# image resize function returns black image

Tags: php, image, gd

I have a function that takes the window size and if the image width is less than the window width shows the original image or if the image is wider than the windw resizes the image to fit.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

$file="../images/photos/".$row['file'];

//check the size of the source image
$x = getimagesize($file);            
$srcWidth  = $x['0'];
$srcHeight = $x['1'];

$ratio = $srcWidth/$srcHeight;

if($srcWidth < $width){
    //use original
    $img="<img src='".$file."' alt='original image' />";
}else{
    $height=round($srcHeight/$ratio);
    echo "Resize ".$file."\n";
    echo "Create new image ".$width." wide and ".$height." high"; 
    //$img="<img src='".$file."' style='width:".$width."px; height:auto' />";
    $img="<img src='image-resize.php?src=$file&width=$width&height=$height' alt='resized-image' />";
}

echo "<div class='photo'>";

if($row['dateAdded']<>""){
   echo "<p>Added on: ".date('m/d/Y', $row['dateAdded'])." by ".$row['username']."</p>";
}else{
   echo "<p>&nbsp;</p>";
}
if($row['title']<>""){
    echo "<h4>".htmlentities($row['title'],ENT_QUOTES)."</h4>";
}
echo $img;
echo "</div>";
}
```

This is the resize file - I have stripped it down as much as possible but still can spot the problem. The images are definitely jpg

```
<?php
// image source and extension
$src = $_GET[src];
$width = $_GET[width];
$height = $_GET[height];

//echo $imgSrc;

//get image path info
$ext_parts = pathinfo($src);

//get file extension type
//$ext=$ext_parts['extension'];
$ext="jpg";

    $img_base = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);

    //output the image directly to the browser
    header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($img_base, null, 100);

    /*
    if($ext == "jpg"){ 
        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($img_base, null, 100);  
    }
    if($ext == "gif"){ 
        header('Content-type: image/gif');
        imagegif($img_base); 
    }
    if($ext == "png"){ 
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($img_base, null, 9); 
    }
    */
    //clear memory
    imagedestroy($img_base);

?>
```

This link shows the problem
http://www.searchforsites.co.uk/mobile/images-test.php?id=1&width=500

Any guidance greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

You simple have to use [imagecopyresized](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) function or [imagecopyresampled](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) to create your image thumbnails. You should really take a look at PHP documentation - there are complete examples how to create thumbnails in PHP on those functions' manual pages.